# delete constant columns spark having issue with timestamp column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

hi guys i did this code that allows to drop columns with constant values.
i start by computing the standard deviation i then drop the ones having standard equal to zero ,but i got this issue when having a column which has a timestamp type what to do

cannot resolve 'stddev_samp(`time.1`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires double type, however, '`time.1`' is of timestamp type.;;

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
//val df = spark.range(1, 1000).withColumn("X2", lit(0)).toDF("X1","X2")
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest2.txt")
df.show(5)
//df.columns.map(p=>s"`${p}`")
//val aggs = df.columns.map(c => stddev(c).as(c)) 
val aggs = df.columns.map(p=>stddev(s"`${p}`").as(p))
val stddevs = df.select(aggs: _*)
val columnsToKeep: Seq[Column] = stddevs.first  // Take first row
  .toSeq  // convert to Seq[Any]
  .zip(df.columns)  // zip with column names
  .collect {
    // keep only names where stddev != 0
    case (s: Double, c) if s != 0.0  => col(c) 
  }
df.select(columnsToKeep: _*).show(5,false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `stddev`

`stddev` is only defined on numeric columns. If you want to compute the standard deviation of a `date` column you will need to convert it to a time stamp first:

```
scala> var myDF = (0 to 10).map(x => (x, scala.util.Random.nextDouble)).toDF("id", "rand_double")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, rand_double: double]

scala> myDF = myDF.withColumn("Date", current_date())
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, rand_double: double ... 1 more field]

scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- rand_double: double (nullable = false)
 |-- Date: date (nullable = false)


scala> myDF.show
+---+-------------------+----------+
| id|        rand_double|      Date|
+---+-------------------+----------+
|  0| 0.3786008989478248|2017-03-21|
|  1| 0.5968932024004612|2017-03-21|
|  2|0.05912760417456575|2017-03-21|
|  3|0.29974600653895667|2017-03-21|
|  4| 0.8448407414817856|2017-03-21|
|  5| 0.2049495659443249|2017-03-21|
|  6| 0.4184846380144779|2017-03-21|
|  7|0.21400484330739022|2017-03-21|
|  8| 0.9558142791013501|2017-03-21|
|  9|0.32530639391058036|2017-03-21|
| 10| 0.5100585655062743|2017-03-21|
+---+-------------------+----------+

scala> myDF = myDF.withColumn("Date", unix_timestamp($"Date"))
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, rand_double: double ... 1 more field]

scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- rand_double: double (nullable = false)
 |-- Date: long (nullable = true)


scala> myDF.show
+---+-------------------+----------+
| id|        rand_double|      Date|
+---+-------------------+----------+
|  0| 0.3786008989478248|1490072400|
|  1| 0.5968932024004612|1490072400|
|  2|0.05912760417456575|1490072400|
|  3|0.29974600653895667|1490072400|
|  4| 0.8448407414817856|1490072400|
|  5| 0.2049495659443249|1490072400|
|  6| 0.4184846380144779|1490072400|
|  7|0.21400484330739022|1490072400|
|  8| 0.9558142791013501|1490072400|
|  9|0.32530639391058036|1490072400|
| 10| 0.5100585655062743|1490072400|
+---+-------------------+----------+
```

At this point all of the columns are numeric so your code will run fine:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val aggs = myDF.columns.map(p=>stddev(s"`${p}`").as(p))
val stddevs = myDF.select(aggs: _*)
val columnsToKeep: Seq[Column] = stddevs.first  // Take first row
  .toSeq  // convert to Seq[Any]
  .zip(myDF.columns)  // zip with column names
  .collect {
    // keep only names where stddev != 0
    case (s: Double, c) if s != 0.0  => col(c)
  }
myDF.select(columnsToKeep: _*).show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+-------------------+
|id |rand_double        |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |0.3786008989478248 |
|1  |0.5968932024004612 |
|2  |0.05912760417456575|
|3  |0.29974600653895667|
|4  |0.8448407414817856 |
|5  |0.2049495659443249 |
|6  |0.4184846380144779 |
|7  |0.21400484330739022|
|8  |0.9558142791013501 |
|9  |0.32530639391058036|
|10 |0.5100585655062743 |
+---+-------------------+

aggs: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(stddev_samp(id) AS `id`, stddev_samp(rand_double) AS `rand_double`, stddev_samp(Date) AS `Date`)
stddevs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: double, rand_double: double ... 1 more field]
columnsToKeep: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = ArrayBuffer(id, rand_double)
```

### Using `countDistinct`

All that being said, it would be more general to use `countDistinct`:

```
scala> val distCounts = myDF.select(myDF.columns.map(c => countDistinct(c) as c): _*).first.toSeq.zip(myDF.columns)
distCounts: Seq[(Any, String)] = ArrayBuffer((11,id), (11,rand_double), (1,Date))]

scala> distCounts.foldLeft(myDF)((accDF, dc_col) => if (dc_col._1 == 1) accDF.drop(dc_col._2) else accDF).show
+---+-------------------+
| id|        rand_double|
+---+-------------------+
|  0| 0.3786008989478248|
|  1| 0.5968932024004612|
|  2|0.05912760417456575|
|  3|0.29974600653895667|
|  4| 0.8448407414817856|
|  5| 0.2049495659443249|
|  6| 0.4184846380144779|
|  7|0.21400484330739022|
|  8| 0.9558142791013501|
|  9|0.32530639391058036|
| 10| 0.5100585655062743|
+---+-------------------+
```